# ingress-nginx: Unable to call one service from another using axios

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've created 2 services using node-express:

1. webbff-service: All incoming http requests to the express server to pass through this service
2. identity-service: To handle user auth and other user details

webbff service will pass on the request to identity service if url matches a respective pattern.

**webbff-service: server.js file:**

```
const dotEnv = require('dotenv');
dotEnv.config();
dotEnv.config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` });

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/webbff/test', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'web bff route working OK!' });
});

const axios = require('axios');
app.use('/webbff/api/identity', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.url);
  const url = `http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local:8000/api/identity${req.url}`;
  axios
    .get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      res.json(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error });
    });
});

// Error handler middleware
const errorMiddleware = require('./error/error-middleware');
app.use(errorMiddleware);

const PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 8000;
const startServer = async () => {
  app
    .listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit();
    });
};

startServer();
```

**Deployment file of webbff-service:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webbff-service-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webbff-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webbff-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: webbff-service
          image: ajhavery/webbff-service
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webbff-service-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: webbff-service
  ports:
    - name: webbff-service
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
```

**Identity service** is a simple node express app - which accepts all urls of format: /api/identity
It has a test route - /api/identity/test to test the routes

**Deployment file of Identity service:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: identity-service-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: identity-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: identity-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: identity-service
          image: ajhavery/identity-service
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: identity-service-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: identity-service
  ports:
    - name: identity-service
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
```

Both these services are deployed on meraretail.dev - a local service which I achieved by modifying /etc/hosts:

127.0.0.1 meraretail.dev

**Skaffold.yaml file used for deployment on local kubernetes cluster with 1 node:**

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta28
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./kubernetes/*
build:
  local:
    push: false # don't push images to dockerhub
  artifacts:
    - image: ajhavery/webbff-service
      context: webbff-service
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - dest: .
            src: 'src/**/*.js'
    - image: ajhavery/identity-service
      context: identity-service
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - dest: .
            src: 'src/**/*.js'
```

**Routing between files is handled using ingress-nginx service:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-public-svc
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: meraretail.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: '/webbff/?(.*)'
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: webbff-service-svc
                port:
                  number: 8000
          - path: '/api/identity/?(.*)'
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: identity-service-svc
                port:
                  number: 8000
```

Though, when I try to access the route: https://meraretail.dev/webbff/api/identity/test

In postman, I receive error - BAD gateway